# Unauthorized response from Rest call to CRM using adal.js

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, single-page-application, adal, adal.js

So ive been trying to use REST calls from an external application into Microsoft Dynamics CRM and am being return with an unauthorized response, I follow Microsoft tutorial and code exactly (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt595797.aspx) only changing:
 Organization URI, tenant, clientID, and page URL to my information along with changing authContext.acquireToken(organizationURI, retrieveAccounts) to authContext.acquireToken(ClientID, retrieveAccounts). I am able to login and everything but once I make a REST call I got an Unauthorized response, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you parse the token via http://jwt.calebb.net/ do you have any roles? if not, try deleting the app in portal.azure.com and recreating it (and the relevant permissions) in manage.windowsazure.com (the old portal). I had a similar issue - getting 401 because my token had no roles - and that worked

Comment: in fact, see https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/7069592-add-ability-to-create-service-principal-and-grant which seens to confirm that it works in old but not new portal

Comment: Hi Dom, do you have any update?

Comment: Sorry for no responding earlier, but I had an idea what may have been wrong. I though that maybe the reason I was unauthorized was because I was not a user inside the application. Unfortunately once I was added as a user it did not change anything. My token does not show roles, and do not have the ability to change delete and create a new one (business rules). But I can ask my manager to create a new one on the old portal and add permissions so maybe that may work

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the sample to walk through the trial, you can leverage chrome develop tool to get the access token, and use Postman or fiddler to generate the http request call with the access token as the authorization header. To detect what the exact error message.

[image]

As according to the description in the post your provide:

> You must have a Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online) system user account with administrator role for the Microsoft Office 365.

If you get any error like "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation",
you can try to upgrade the role of the AD application you use to a administrator permission. Run the following commands in `PowerShell`:

```
Connect-MsolService
$ClientIdWebApp = '{your_AD_application_client_id}'
$webApp = Get-MsolServicePrincipal –AppPrincipalId $ClientIdWebApp
#use Add-MsolRoleMember to add it to "Company Administrator" role).
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleName "Company Administrator" -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal -RoleMemberObjectId $webApp.ObjectId
```

If you have any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Im not actually allowed to use chrome, only IE in where I am, along with Postman and Fiddle not being approved software for me to use